# Mostrar solo la primera imagen en template en Django

Tags: python, django

Tengo dos modelos: el primer modelo Property y el segundo modelo Property Imagen:

```
Class Property(models.model):
    title = models.CharField()


Class PropertyImage(models.model):
    property = modelos.Foreignkey(Property, related_name='images')
    imagen = models.ImageField()
```

PropertyImage es donde se guardan las imágenes de las propiedades y esta relacionada al primer modelo con una foreign key.

Conozco que para obtener el url de la primera imagen de una propiedad en una consulta haría algo como esto:

```
p1 = Property.objects.first() # la primera propiedad
p1.images.first() # la primera imagen de la propiedad 1
```

Mi duda es si al template le envió un query donde estén todas las propiedades (o filtradas de acuerdo al caso) como haría dentro del template para mostrar solo el url de la primera imagen para cada propiedad?

He intentado usar la función first dentro del template pero me marca error de sintaxis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No deberías agregar lógica de programación a las plantillas.

Tu mejor opción es agregar una *propiedad* a tu modelo:

```
Class Property(models.model):
    title = models.CharField()

    @property
    def primera(self):
        return self.image.all()[0]
```

Para mostrar el url dentro del Template:

```
{% for property in properties %}
  <img src="{{ property.primera.image.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

**Notas**:

- No estoy seguro que exista la función `first()`, pero `[0]` te regresa el primer registro de un *QuerySet*.

> Se usan las ***relaciones inversas*** y esta es la documentación: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Comment: Lo de `images` fue en un error de dedo, ya lo edite. Si existe `first()`, no se desde cuando la verdad. Por ultimo en el template, para obtener el url seria algo como `{{ property.primera.image.url }}`?

Comment: Si, así se usa. Si quieres ahorrarte teclas, solo agrega ése detalle a la propiedad. Que trabaje tu modelo, no tu plantilla.